How to get Azure Functions [Javascript] raw Body data for HMAC signature verification (Twitch EventSub validation)
I have a similar request from the user here where I'm trying to generate an HMAC that matches the signature of a validation request from Twitch EventSub.
I'm following the example from Twtich for validating, but I cannot get a body that will create a matching HMAC.
With v4 functions removing request.rawBody I've tried:

request.text()
request.json() and then stringify
request.arrayBuffer() and process stream
request.blob()
as well as adding the await request.text() to the hmac update action directly (as recommended in the other linked SO question) without success.

How can I get the raw body out of the request's raw body in Azure Fuctions v4 Javascript?
Code I'm working with is below:
app.http('twitchCommandHandler', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const signature = request.headers.get('Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Signature');
        const timestamp = request.headers.get('Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Timestamp').toLowerCase();
        const messageId = request.headers.get('Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Id').toLowerCase();
        const messageType = request.headers.get('Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Type').toLowerCase();
        const body = await request.text();  

        const message = messageId + timestamp + body;
        const hmac = 'sha256=' + (crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.TWITCH_WEBHOOK_SECRET).update(message).digest('hex'));

        const verifyHmac = crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(hmac), Buffer.from(signature));

        
        if (verifyHmac) {
            return { status: 200, body: body.challenge, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } };
        } else {
            return { status: 401 };
        }
    }
});

I've tried all the available methods for getting the request body from Azure Functions, including just request.body but no results create a matching HMAC to the signature provided from Twitch.  I would expect to be able to get the raw body that was used to generate a signature to validate that signature with the appropriate matching secret.

As the document show V4 has changed the request body types.
V4 return full data based on the types you have requested.
        const body = await request.text();          // returtns body in text format
        const body = await request.json();          //retuns bosy in json format
        const body = await request.formData();      //retuns bosy in formData
        const body = await request.arrayBuffer();   //retuns bosy in array Buffer
        const bosy = await request.blob();          //retuns bosy in blob format

If you want to use bosy data for future processing. I would suggest using await request.json();, as you can use json object data for multiple data processing.
MY Code :-
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const body = await request.json();
        

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: body
        }
    }
});

OUTPUT:

As you can see i am using await request.json() which is retuning text in json format.


I have no issues getting the body and its data as needed, what I need is to get the RAW BODY information, to create a hash to compare against the signature provided as a header.  The JSON object using what you refer to would generate a different hash from the data used to generate the signature provided.  I need the RAW BODY data to generate a matching hash and I'm not sure how to properly get that with the latest v4 node Functions
